# In grid view control I am trying to collect of "user request no" in 1st column

Tags: gridview, datagridview

In grid view control, I am trying to collect of `user request no` in 1st column but I don't want to show this column when I set visible=false , It collects null value.

Suggest some code to capture data from invisible column in grid view control.

grid view control fill data from sql data source.

Comment: GridView or DataGridView ? Webforms or Winforms ?

Comment: Please show the code for what you've done so far.

Comment: I am using following code string LID = GVdilivery.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

Answer (score 0):

It is a Web form.

[It is the Web form Grid view control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqpzH.png)

In the below table I don't want to show laundry ID when any customer selects any row I want to hold ID in session. When Column visible it work properly but when i set property visible=false It doesn't work and holds null value.

[I set property visible = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUnmn.png)